# MVC Razor DropDownListFor value not set in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to make a razor view that can post a model to my controller.

I've added a dropdown, however `platform` is always `null` when i post to my controller.

What am i doing wrong?

This is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "form" }))
{
    @{
        var platformList = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem(){ Value="I", Text="iOS"},
            new SelectListItem(){ Value="A", Text="Android"},
        };
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.platform, "Plattform", new { @for = "inputPlatform", @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.platform, platformList, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "inputPlatform" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is my model

```
public class RegistrationModel
{
    public String platform { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(RegistrationModel RegistrationModelViewModel)
{

}
```

Comment: I dont see a submit button.  Could you be posting the wrong form?

Comment: Also, have you examined what is being sent over the wire, using a tool like Fiddler?

Comment: Why you decorated the actionMethod with `AllowAnonymous`? Remove it, rebuild the project and see the results.

Comment: Ensure the POST request returning proper `SelectList` value. I preferred passing `SelectList` from controller when the view called with GET method. Other than that, the provided code seems working fine.

Comment: The code you have shown works perfectly fine and the value of `RegistrationModelViewModel.platform` in the POST method will be either "I" or "A". If its not working for you, then its due to code you have not shown us.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your view to work. There appears to be a formatting issue with the drop down declaration. It has an extra comma and was missing a end }. I kept getting a parse error, which is odd as you say you can get the post to work.

Anyway, I've created an example below which works and so I hope is of some use.

Model

```
 public class RegistrationModel
 {
        public string platform { get; set; }
 }
```

View

```
@model TestMVC.Models.RegistrationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Register", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "form" }))
{
    var platformList = new List<SelectListItem>() {new SelectListItem(){ Value="I", Text="iOS"}, new SelectListItem(){ Value="A", Text="Android"}};

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.platform, "Plattform", new {@for = "inputPlatform", @class = "col-lg-3 control-label"})
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.platform, platformList, new {@class = "form-control", @id = "inputPlatform"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
}
```

Controller

```
 public class RegisterController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegistrationModel model)
        {
            //Do something here;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with OP's code and there is no missing `}` and the extra comma make no difference at all (and who on earth upvoted this)

Comment: That's a bit harsh. I'm only trying to help. When I put OPs code into a view.. it doesn't work for me... maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The code you have shown is identical to OP's except that you have moved  the `@{ var platformList ... }` code  exactly as it is before the form instead of inside. And OP has stated the value is `null` in the POST method, which could never have occurred it the view throwing an error.